# "Странный" символ в конце файла

Tags: c, файлы, ввод

Написал программку для копирования содержимого txt файла из 1 в 2. Почти всё работает, только я не понимаю как пофиксить запись последнего символа?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define size 101


int main()
{
FILE* read;
FILE* write;

read = fopen("1.txt", "r");
write = fopen("2.txt", "w");

char buffer[size];

char c;



if(read != NULL)
{
   while(c != EOF)
   {
       c = getc(read);
       fprintf(write,"%c", c);
   }

   fclose(read);
   fclose(write);
}

else
{
    printf("File is doesn't exist\n");
}
```

[image: wtf]

Comment: А в `1.txt` что находится?

Comment: @gil9red, неважно, но вообще - `Hello World`.

Comment: Там находится Hello World

Comment: классическая ошибка... как обычно проверку на EOF надо делать после `getc()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> char c;
> ```

Неверно. EOF имеет тип int, когда его урезаешь до `char`, старшие байты теряются и будет некий символ, который будет ошибочно рассматриваться как EOF (буква `я` в win1251).

> ```
> while(c != EOF)
> ```

Не инициализированную переменную сравнивать с чем-то - плохая идея.

> ```
> c = getc(read);
> fprintf(write,"%c", c);
> ```

Прочитали символ и вывели. Неизвестно, успешно прочитали или нет - сравнение с EOF будет уже потом, после того, как произойдёт его вывод. При достижении EOF выводится лишняя буква `я`.

---

Вот правильный код:

```
for (int c; (c=getc(read)) != EOF; )
  fprintf(write, "%c", c);
```

---

Кстати

> ```
> fprintf(write,"%c", c);
> ```

можно заменить на `putc(c, write)`, но тут по желанию.

Answer (score 8):

Вы объявляете переменную `c`, потом проверяете у нее значение, а потом инициализируете.

При этом, если `getc()` вернула `EOF` вы все равно вызываете запись этого символа в файл `fprintf(write,"%c", c);`

Вам нужно переписать цикл к нормальному виду

```
c = getc(read);
while(c != EOF)
{
   fprintf(write,"%c", c);
   c = getc(read);
}
```

При этом переменную `c` нужно объявить не как `char`, а как `int`. Иначе цикл у вас будет прекращаться, как только в файле встретится с кодом 255 (в кодировке Win1251 это буква `я`).

Comment: У него в коде `char c`...

Answer (score 7):

Все не просто просто,а очень просто :)

```
int c;

...

while((c = getc(read)) != EOF)
{
    fprintf(write,"%c", c);
}
```