# Лишний символ с кодом "-1" перед EOF

Tags: c, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

При записи содержимого из файла input в файл output перед концом файла считывается ещё один символ с кодом "-1", который выводится в output как символ "я", чего быть не должно.

```
FILE *input_file, *output_file;
char *file_name, c, keyword[] = {"ìàìà"};
int v, i, j, mem_s;
char *str = NULL;

while (!feof(input_file))
{
    v = 1; mem_s = 80; i = 0; str = NULL;
    while (v && !feof(input_file))
    {
        mem_s *= 1.2;
        if ((str = (char*) realloc (str, mem_s*sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        {
            printf ("Memory allocation error 1.\n");
            return 2;
        }
        c = '1';
        while (c != '.' && !feof(input_file) && i < mem_s)
        {
            str[i] = c = fgetc(input_file);
            printf ("%d ", c);
            i++;
        }
        if (c == '.') v = 0;
    }
    printf ("\n%s\n", str);
    if ((str = (char*) realloc (str, (i+1)*sizeof(char))) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Memory allocation error.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf ("\n%s\n", str);
    if (strstr (str, keyword) == NULL)  fputs(str, output_file); /*fwrite (str, sizeof(char), i, output_file);*/
    free (str);
    if (feof(input_file)) printf ("END FOUND\n");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Странный" символ в конце файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932414/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: EOF (это ваш -1) как раз при чтении и возвращается. Именно после его появления `feof()` будет возвращать true. Т.е.вызывать `feof()` до чтения бессмысленно. И читать, вызывая `fgetc()`, надо в **int (а не char)** переменную

Answer (score 2):

Это и есть признак конца файла. Потому что вы неверно выполняете проверку на конец файла - она срабатывает только **после** неудачного чтения. А ваше неудачное чтение и состоит в возврате `EOF` (вообще-то по хорошему надо читать не в `char`, а в `int`, чтоб не путать `EOF` и `я`).

См. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Comment: Только не *по хорошему*, а **обязательно**